# C# moving object with keys doesnt work like i want

Tags: c#, object, key, move

I hate to ask, but i really dont find the answer.
Im new to C# ( came from C++) and i wanted to programm a little stupid game.
Everything works so far. But now i want to move an object with the wasd keys.
The problem is, it moves, but it just makes a small step, waits a moment and then moves like i want it to. like when you hold a key when you write something.
Here is the code

```
            private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) // Steuerung
    {
        collision.PlayerCollisionAgainstWall(this, player);


        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) player.pos_y += player.r_speed_y;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) player.pos_y += player.speed_y;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) player.pos_x += player.r_speed_x;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) player.pos_x += player.speed_x;

    }
```

r_speed is -10
speed is 10
but i think thats not important

I also tried it with the KeyPress event.

EDIT: I just made a normal Windows Form Application

Comment: Side note: please avoid "thank you" notes, "new here", "good day" and other text not directly related to the question. Also consider using search engines to see if similar questions where asked before.

Comment: I did not make a WPF application. So that wont work for me. I searched allready and if there is allready an answer, then my wording wasnt right.